# Bi-grams by date

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, countvectorizer

I have the following dataset:

```
       Date                  D
_       
0   01/18/2020  shares recipes ... - news updates · breaking news emails · lives to remem...
1   01/18/2020  both sides of the pineapple slices with olive oil. ... some of my other support go-to's i...
2   01/18/2020  honey, tea tree oil ...learn more from webmd about honey ...
3   01/18/2020  years of downtown arts | times leaderas the local community dealt with concerns, pet...
4   01/18/2020  brooklyn, ny | opentableblood orange, arugula, hazelnuts, on toast. charcuterie. $16.00. smoked ...
5   01/19/2020  santa maria di leuca - we the italiansthe sounds of the taranta, the smell of tomatoes, olive oil...
6   01/19/2020  abuse in amish communities : nprit's been a minute with sam sanders · code switch · throughline ...
7   01/19/2020  fast, healthy recipe ideas – cbs new ...toss the pork cubes with chili powder, oregano, cumin, c...
9   01/19/2020  100; 51-100 | csnyi have used oregano oil, coconut oil, famciclovir, an..
```

I am interested in a dataframe which shows bi-grams' frequencies by Date.
Currently I am doing as follows:

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word', stop_words=stop_words)
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['D'])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0] 
pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['Frequency']).sort_values(by='Frequency',ascending=False)
```

But it does not show the bi-grams by Date, only their frequency.
I would like expect something like this (**expected output**):

```
Date           Bi-gram      Frequency
01/18/2020     bi-gram_1     43
               bi-gram_2     12
               ...
01/19/2020     bi-gram_5     42
               bi-gram_6     23
```

and so on. `bi-grams_1, bi-grams_2`, ... are just used as example.

Any advice on how I can get such a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The way I went about this problem was to reorganize your original dataframe so that the overarching key was the date and within each date was a list sentences:

   ```
    new_df = {}
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] not in new_df.keys():
        new_df[row[0]] = []

    new_df[row[0]].append(row[1])
   ```

row[0] is the date and row[1] is the data

The output will look something like this:

```
    {'1/18/20': ['shares recipes news updates breaking news google', 'shares 
    recipes news updates breaking news seo'], '1/19/20': ['shares recipes news 
    updates breaking news emails', 'shares recipes news updates breaking news 
    web']}
```

2. Now you can iterate over each date and get the frequency of each bigram within that date. All the data is stored in a similar dataframe as you had above and appended to a list. At the end, the list will contain *n* dataframe where *n* is the number of dates in your dataset:

   ```
    word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word', 
    stop_words=stop_words)
    frames = []
    for date,values in new_df.items():
        sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(values)
        frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0] 
        results = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['Frequency']).sort_values(by='Frequency',ascending=False)

        frames.append(results)
   ```

OR
if you want the date to show up on all rows of the dataframe you can modify step 2 to be:

```
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word', 
stop_words=stop_words)
frames = []
for date,values in new_df.items():
    sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(values)
    frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0] 
    results = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['Frequency']).sort_values(by='Frequency',ascending=False)
    results["Date"] = [date for i in range(len(results))]

    frames.append(results)
```

3. Finally, you can concatenate the dataframes together:

   ```
    pd.concat(frames, keys=[k for k in new_df.keys()])
   ```

***Some improvements you could make would be to find away to re-index the dataframe within pandas itself instead of making a new dictionary.